# AOSP Launcher Widget Dialog

Tags: android, android-source, launcher

I am modifying the AOSP laucnher's code. I have added my widgets shorctcuts in **default_workspace.xml**. All the app shortcuts are coming except the default Settings app **Power Toggle widget**. I spent hours in debugging and came to conclusion , that it was happening due to this widget popup - [image]

Now my question is, is this part of launcher3 or is it a OS generated dialog ? I am not able to locate from where this dialog is getting popped up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [uiautomatorviewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#uia-viewer) to figure out the package and by association the process and the application.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to Launcher3's Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
```